# Created receiving address in Bitcoin Core but deleted it before receiving bitcoins

Tags: transactions, address, receiving

I created a receiving address in Bitcoin Core, sent myself some coins from localbitcoins.com and - silly me - deleted the receiving address from Bitcoin Core.

tradeblock.com shows the transaction with a "confirmed balance" but I haven't received the coins in my wallet. Is there any way to restore the address in Bitcoin Core?

Thanks!

PS: I wasn't specific enough:

1. I created a "request payment" in Bitcoin Core and used the payment information address tto send coins from my localbitcoins.com account.
2. I deleted the "requested payments" entry in the Bitcoin Core wallet before coins were received.
3. Blockchain.info shows the a "total received" and a "final balance" so I presume the transaction was concluded. Yet, after 30++ hours, the coins haven't been received by my Bitcoin Core wallet.

Is the transaction somewhat hanging there because it can't find the address that I sent the coins to but deleted?

@murch: Thanks for the hint. You are correct: I know the address, the transaction appears to be confirmed on Tradeblock but the balance does not appear in my Bitcoin Core wallet (fully synced).

Comment: Did you save the private key anywhere? How did you create the receiving address? How did you delete it?

Comment: Indeed, I should have been more specific. Sorry!:

1. Created a "request payment" in Bitcoin Core and used the payment information address tto send coins from my localbitcoins.com account.
2. Deleted the "requested payments" entry in the Bitcoin Core wallet before coins were received. 
3. Blockchain.info shows the a "total received" and a "final balance" so I presume the transaction was concluded.

After 20 hours, the coins haven't been received by my Bitcoin Core wallet. Is the transaction somewhat hanging there because it can't find the address that I sent the coins to but deleted?

Comment: So, you do know the address, the transaction appears to be confirmed, but the balance is not appearing in Bitcoin Core? Please put clarifications into the original posts, comments are considered transient and might get deleted at some point.

Comment: Is you Bitcoin Core fully synced? (does it show a "X weeks remaining..." at the bottom?)

Comment: Yes, it is fully synced.

Comment: (1) Does blockchain.info show the transaction as being confirmed, and how many confirmations? (2) You might double check that Bitcoin Core is *staying* in sync by checking the block number and date from the debug window against blockchain.info.  (3) I would try running Bitcoin Core with the `-rescan` option.  Bitcoin Core is designed pretty carefully to *never* delete private keys so I would guess they are still there.

Comment: Thanks Nate! 1) It shows 99 confirmations. 2) I compared the block numbers, both in my wallet's debug window and the last one shown in blockchain.info are identical. 3) I ran the rescan option but the balance still doesn't show up. Sigh.

Comment: Is there actually a way to retrieve/show the previously used receiving addresses?